# Jest Mock a destructured import/require

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

How can mock a destructured import in the form of

```
const {mymodule} = require('@org/package')
```

I have a custom library in a private repository that exports a function from the index.js file like this

```
// index.js
exports.mymodule = require('./mymodule')
```

Using jest I tried to mock the module like this

```
jest.mock('@org/package', () => ({
   func: jest.fn()
}))
```

However, when I check the value of `{module}` it remains null.
Then, when remove the curly brackets from `module`, it becomes populated with the mock module.

How can I mock the destructured module?

Comment: By providing `module` property? Currently `jest.mock` has no mention of `module`. Also, you shouldn't use module name because it's in conflict with CommonJS `module`.

Comment: module is not the actual name I'm using, but i will edit the post for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module object is supposed to have `mymodule` property, while mocked module doesn't have it. To ensure the interoperation with ES modules, CommonJS export should have `__esModule` as well:

```
jest.mock('@org/package', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  mymodule: {
    func: jest.fn()
  }
}))
```

Comment: in case i try ```const myFn = jest.mock('@org/package', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  myFn: {
    func: jest.fn()
  }
}));
/* some code */
expect(myFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```
it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sergii jest.mock doesn't return mocked module. it just mocks it without evaluating it, you still need to have `import { myFn } ...` where you use it.